# auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment - Firebase, EXPLORER 11, Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, firebase-authentication, internet-explorer-11, google-authentication

Dears, 
I'm using **GOOGLE SCRIPT** and **GOOGLE SPREADSHEET**.

From an **HTML sidebar** built with GOOGLE SCRIPT I'm trying to **LOGIN WITH FIREBASE ( Google Sign-In )**.

Here is the **code** to open the **sidebar**:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile( 'menu' )
        .evaluate()
        .setTitle( 'Amis' )
        .setWidth( 500 )
        .setSandboxMode( HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME );
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .showSidebar( html );
```

Here is the code for FIREBASE **( Google Sign-In )**:

```
        /**
        * show a popup with the google login
        */
       function loginWithGoogle() {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup( provider ).then( function( result ) {
            onLoggedState(result.user);
        } ).catch( function( error ) {
            console.log('ERROR', error);            
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            var email = error.email;
            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            var credential = error.credential;
            // ...
        } );
       }
```

It works for Chrome, Edge , Firefox **but NOT FOR INTERNET EXPLORE 11**.

Here the exception:

```
error.code      "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment"
error.message       "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled."
```

Comment: Do you happen to have 3rd party cookies/data disabled in your IE 11 browser?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked and unfortunately are enabled.